# ERROR: unused argument ("Ndv3")

Tags: r, shiny, rcharts

I'm new to R. While trying to implement NDV3 charts using rCharts in shiny I'm getting the following error:

> ERROR: unused argument ("NDV3")

```
mainPanel(  
    showOutput("visual", "NDV3")  
  )

output$visual <- renderChart({  
        dat <- getdata()  
        n1 <- nPlot(input$var1~input$var2,group   =input$var3,data=dat,type='multiBarChart')  
        n1$addParams(dom = "visual")  
        return(n1)
})
```

Comment: It is nvd3. You have a typo, and also it should be in lowercase.

Comment: If you are using `input`, dont use the formula interface as your input objects are strings. So use `nPlot(x = input$var1, y = input$var2, ...)`